# update linq to entity

Tags: c#, linq

Am trying to write an linq to entity update query equivalent to the below sql query

```
update INVOICES set STATUS=1 where INVOICE=165438
```

My Linq to Entity

```
 var db = new MyEntities();
            var query =
            from t in db.INVOICES
            where
            t.INVOICE1 == "165438"
            select t;
            foreach (var t in query)
            {
                t.STATUS ="1";
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
```

Am not sure ,please some one throw me some help .

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: One thing that's wrong is that `db` implements IDisposable, and there's no `using` keyword or other sign that db.Dispose() is eventually called.

Comment: am just double check bcoz right now i can't test again this code ,i have few exception in my project,that's why

Comment: Other than the missing `using` the code looks fine assuming INVOICE1 and STATUS are strings.

Comment: Also... please don't post code just to have someone else look it over.  That's not what we're here for.  Post code along with a concrete question when you are stuck or something is wrong.

Comment: Am sorry guys,i shouldn't post this question.Am closing this question now and thanks to all.

Comment: try to revise your question.. `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag your entity with the `EntityState.Modified` to tell the EntityFramework to update it in your database

```
var query = /*Your query*/;
foreach (var t in query)
{
    t.STATUS ="1";
    db.Entry(t).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
}

db.SaveChanges();
```